# Tab stops are messed up after rarer unicode characters

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

In vscode, when I open a file containing unicode characters,
I notice that tabs do not always advance to the next tab stop.
For example, the following might be part of an ASCII-flavor table

```
a<tab>b<tab>c<tab>d<tab>e
α<tab>β<tab>γ<tab>δ<tab>ε
<tab><tab>ℂ<tab><tab>
```

While sublime text renders it *correctly*(IMO)

[image]

vscdoe has a different idea

[image]

As I understand it, vscode renders a tab by
replacing it with a proper number of space characters.
So if there are characters showing using proportional fonts,
no integer number of spaces will make it to the proper stop.
(See [this related issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108755).)

So my question is, how can I fix this?
Is it possible to tell vscode that
"Fine, if you were to assume that those unicode characters
are 2 spaces wide when tabbing,
would you please render them as 2 spaces wide?"

Comment: My guess is that this is happening because the font being used doesn't support the math alphanumeric characters, so VS Code is doing font fallback for those characters, and that the width of spaces in the fallback font is different from the default font. Just a guess.

Comment: I have no doubt this is the case. In fact, why don't we push further and assume that there must be some unicode characters not covered by my favorite mono font. In that case, is vscode's *attitude* going to be **screw you and your unicode characters; use Code2000 or I won't let tabbing work**? Because that's how I feel after reading the dev replies in the given issue. (See also issue#1727 and issue#9105; this is not new.)

Comment: Asking for a single monospace font that supports all Unicode characters simply isn't feasible: fonts technically can't support that many characters. Even if count wasn't an issue, there are some Unicode characters that simply couldn't be legible if they had to fit within a single width (unless everything was made very wide—also not a good option). But it does seem reasonable that VSC pursue some fix, which might require going upstream to get new APIs in Chromium.

Comment: I agree with everything you said.